# How does XMLHttpRequest relate to the JS Window object

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, specifications, window-object, webidl

While reading up on `XMLHttpRequest` found out that it is a member of the high level JS global `window` object. For instance:

```js
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, IE7+ ...
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 6 and older
    httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

But I can't confirm this information anywhere else? I looked up here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window to see if I could locate the `XMLHttpRequest` object but there wasn't any mentioning of it. Am I missing something? Just want to make sure I am understanding the correct origin of `XMLHttpRequest` and how it relates to the global `window` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the WebIDL definition for the `XMLHttpRequest` interface](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-xmlhttprequest):

```
[Constructor, Exposed=(Window,DedicatedWorker,SharedWorker)]
interface XMLHttpRequest : XMLHttpRequestEventTarget {
…
}
```

So that requires `XMLHttpRequest` to be exposed from `Window` and also from `DedicatedWorker` and `SharedWorker` (in UAs that actually implement those).